# Pango build error (GTK+3 build)

Tags: c, linux, gtk, cairo, pango

I am building GTK+3 (3.16.6) latest version on my Elementary OS desktop (Ubuntu 12.04) following these installation instructions at [GTK website](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-building.html).

I have successfully built and installed the following packages in `"/opt/gtk"` following the previous link:

- Glib-2.44.1
- GdkPixBuf-2.31
- GOObject-1.44

But when I try to :

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/gtk
```

the output is :

```
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking whether build environment is sane... yes
    checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
    checking for gawk... no
    checking for mawk... mawk
    checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
    checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
    checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
    checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
    checking for native Win32... no
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables... 
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
    checking for style of include used by make... GNU
    checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
    checking for c++... c++
    checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
    checking whether c++ accepts -g... yes
    checking dependency style of c++... gcc3
    checking for sysconf... yes
    checking for getpagesize... yes
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
    checking for ANSI C header files... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
    checking sys/mman.h usability... yes
    checking sys/mman.h presence... yes
    checking for sys/mman.h... yes
    checking how to print strings... printf
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
    checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
    checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
    checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
    checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
    checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
    checking whether ln -s works... yes
    checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
    checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to i686-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
    checking for objdump... objdump
    checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
    checking for dlltool... dlltool
    checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
    checking for ar... ar
    checking for archiver @FILE support... @
    checking for strip... strip
    checking for ranlib... ranlib
    checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
    checking for sysroot... no
    checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
    checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
    checking for mt... mt
    checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
    checking for dlfcn.h... yes
    checking for objdir... .libs
    checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
    checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
    checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
    checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
    checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
    checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
    checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build static libraries... no
    checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... c++ -E
    checking for ld used by c++... /usr/bin/ld
    checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
    checking whether the c++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking for c++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
    checking if c++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
    checking if c++ static flag -static works... yes
    checking if c++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking if c++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
    checking whether the c++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    configure: creating ./config.lt
    config.lt: creating libtool
    checking for some Win32 platform... no
    checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
    checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
    checking for HARFBUZZ... no
    checking for CoreText availability... no
    checking for CAIRO... no
    configure: error: *** Could not enable any backends.
    *** Must have at least one backend to build Pango.
```

But I have **libcairo2-dev** and **libcairo2** installed through apt-get. I read somewhere that the CoreText and HarfBuzz are available through **gnome-core-devel**. When I tried to install the package, i got the following error :

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gnome-core-devel : Depends: gnome-platform-devel (= 1:3.0+6ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libwnck-3-dev (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libmutter-dev (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please help me resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to use [jhbuild](https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeLove/JhbuildIntroduction)? it is made for exactly the purpose of having different versions availiable at the same time

Comment: No, the website says we can just make it.